# Word wrapping in Bootstrap - one or three lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3, and at some point in my page I have a sentence "X Y Z" made of three parts. For instance, it could be "Bud Spencer walks with Terence Hill." where X="Bud Spencer", Y="walks with", Z="Terence Hill."

I want to avoid text wrapping in each of the three parts, so I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="...">
    <span class="text-nowrap">X</span> <span class="text-nowrap">Y</span> <span class="text-nowrap">Z</span>
</div>
```

Ideally I want the users to see the unbroken sentence `X Y Z`, but if the screen is not wide enough I want them to see

```
X
Y
Z
```

and not, for instance

```
X Y
Z
```

In other words, I want to force a wrap of all the three parts in case there isn't enough space for them to stay on the same line.
How can I do it with CSS/Bootstrap?

Comment: Why aren't you using rows and columns?

Comment: Initial research into bootstrap will tell you how to solve this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I am using rows and columns, this is just a single sentence (I edited the question to make it more clear). If you are suggesting to put the different parts of the sentence in different columns, could you please explain how to do it without forcing the columns to have the same width?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the following in bootstrap to achieve this:-

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">X</span>
    <span class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">Y</span>
    <span class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">Z</span>
</div>
```

please look at [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Actually X, Y and Z are parts of a sentence, and I don't want them to end up in three columns of equal width. I'm going to edit the question to make it clear.